How to share a global function between .m file and .mm file (obj c and obj c++) with common header file?
abc.h
/**
 @function  GetInputSizeFromUsage
 @abstract  return frame width and height from usage
 @param     usage   PPVEUsage to be inqure
 @param     width   (out) the input width for usage
 @param     height  (out) the input height for usage
 */
void GetInputSizeFromUsage(PPVEUsage usage, size_t *width, size_t *height);

file1.m
#import <abc.h>
void GetInputSizeFromUsage(PPVEUsage usage, size_t *width, size_t *height)
{
    switch(usage) {
        case UsageLandscape848x480:
            *width = 848;
            *height = 480;
            break;

        default:
            *width = 0;
            *height = 0;
            break;
    }

}

// This file uses this above function in various other functions and is fine to compile

file2.mm
#import <abc.h>

size_t GetInputSizeFromUsage(PPVEUsage usage)
{
    size_t width, height;
    GetInputSizeFromUsage(usage, &width, &height);
    return (width * height);
}

Error:
Undefined symbol: GetInputSizeFromUsage(PPVEUsage, unsigned long*, unsigned long*)
The error is due to file2.mm not being able to see the symbol. If I comment it out in file2.mm it compiles fine.
Expecting it to be able to see the symbols

Usually this is due to the order of libraries or objects during the link. The one who call the other must be first.

What if you declare GetInputSizeFromUsage in the .h file with C linkage (using extern "C")?

Objective-C++ is superset of C++ language and all rules of C++ apply here. I.e. when declaring a function you have to deal with so-called name mangling, which alters the function signature in a way that the compiler won't be able to locate it in a Objective-C/C compilation unit. For such scenarios you are supposed to tell the linker to apply C rules when including this header in a C++ compilation unit by employing extern "C" section:
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
void GetInputSizeFromUsage(PPVEUsage usage, size_t *width, size_t *height);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

